# Could not find or load main class com.example.dlp.Inspect

Tags: java, gcloud, google-cloud-dlp

I'm trying to run the DLP inspect command on GCP Cloud shell as shown on the "[example - Inspect a string](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/dlp)" page.

I ran the following commands in this order:

```
mvn clean package (Build was successful)

java -cp target/dlp-samples-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.example.dlp.Inspect -s "My phone number is (123) 456-7890 and my email address is me@somedomain.com"
```

I keep getting the following error:

`Could not find or load main class com.example.dlp.Inspect`

Do I need to do any steps prior to running the command?

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: This simply means that the class `com.example.dlp.Inspect` is not contained in the jar. Check your build.

Answer (score 1):

I'll update the README, but if you have run mvn, you then need to go into the dlp package via "cd dlp" and run the command from there.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/pull/1164

Comment: Thank you Jordanna for updating the docs but I'm still encountering the same issue of the class not being found.  I tried: cd /home/pchang/java-docs-samples/dlp Then java -cp target/dlp-samples-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.example.dlp.Inspect -s "My phone number is (123) 456-7890 and my email address is me@somedomain.com" but no luck.  I would really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Try mvn clean package -DskipTests

Comment: Sorry Jordanna - I did the following "mvn clean package -DskipTests".  After running that command, there was a "target" directory only that was created under my home directory.  Then I ran the following command from my home directory "java -cp dlp/target/dlp-samples-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.example.dlp.Inspect -s "My phone number is (123) 456-7890" but got the following error: "Could not find or load main class com.example.dlp.Inspect".  It would be great if we could get this working so that we don't need to write the Java programs from scratch.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a copy of your output? There must be an error in compilation. After building do you see the jar under dlp/target? Because this worked fine for me I suspect something else wrong with your setup. Did you do this from cloud shell?

Comment: Thank you Jordanna for getting back to me.  We have obtained a different set of program codes from Google (https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/dlp-dataflow-deidentification) that we will pursue.